# ReactJs clear state after modal close

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a modal that fetch() some datas. When the modal closes and than reopen it visualize the old datas for some secs and than update the datas.

I want to avoid that the old datas being displayed, just empty field.
The component is wrote in class way, I have a componentDidUpdate - where I do the fetch().

Any suggestions are welcome!

```
export class InfoCustomer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        clientInfos: {},
        clientCards: {},
        clientSubcsriptions: {},
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.show && !prevProps.show) this.openDetail();
}

openDetail() {

    WGet("Customers/preview", { id: this.props.customerId })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ clientInfos: response.data })
            //  API tessere
            WGet("Cards/customer", { customerId: this.props.customerId })
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({ clientCards: response.data });
                    //  API Abbonamenti
                    WGet("Authorizations/customers/subscriptions", { customerId: this.props.customerId })
                        .then(response => this.setState({ clientSubscriptions: response.data }))
                        .catch((error) => {
                        });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ hasError: true, messageError: error.responseMessages });
        });
}
```

And the return:

```
 return (
        <WModalOperation show={this.props.show} title={customerFullName} maxWidth="md"
            buttons={
                <WiButton variant="ghost" onClick={() => handleOnClose()}>Chiudi</WiButton>}>

            <Grid container  spacing={2} sx={{ height: '100%', overflow: 'hidden' }} >

                {/*Avatar and name*/}
                <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ display: 'grid', height: '100%', maxHeight: '100%', placeSelf: 'center', flexFlow: 'column ' }}>

                    <Grid sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <WiInitialName size='big' photo={clientInfos.profilePictureUrl} alt={clientInfos.firstName} />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid sx={{ display: 'flex', alignContent: 'center', flexFlow: 'column wrap', justifyContent: 'space-around', pl: 1, mt: 2 }}>
                        <Grid sx={{ mb: 3, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}><WiLabel >{customerFullName}</WicLabel> </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>


                {/*4 cards with leftBorder $bool*/}
                <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column wrap', height: '100%', alignItems: 'stretch', flexGrow: '1', gap: '1em', maxHeight: maXHeight }}>
                    {col1ToRender.map((item, i) => <CardContainer key={i} color={leftBorderColor(col1ToRenderParams[i].value)} title={item} content={col1ToRenderParams[i].name} />)}
                </Grid>
                {/*4 cards with leftBorder $bool*/}
                <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column wrap', height: '100%', alignItems: 'stretch', flexGrow: '1', gap: '1em', maxHeight: maXHeight }}>
                    {col2ToRender.map((item, i) => <CardContainer key={i + 4} color={leftBorderColor(col2ToRenderParams[i].value)} title={item} content={col2ToRenderParams[i].name} />)}
                </Grid>
                {/*Customer packages*/}
                <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column ', height: '100%', maxHeight: '368px', overflowY: 'scroll', alignContent: 'center', mt: '16px' }}
                    style={hideScrollbar}                        >
                    {customePackages}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </WiModalOperation>
    )
}
```

}

I have done this:

```
 const handleOnClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            clientCards: {},
            clientInfos: {},
            clientSubscriptions: {},
        })
        this.props.show = !this.props.show
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, including specific details about your attempt and what isn't working as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: use `redux` or any `react context` . I recently did did with redux.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

## Reset the state to empty

So assuming you're using the useState hook you can trigger another set state and empty the data.

### Pseudo code example

```
const MyComp () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
   /** query logic **/
   setState(data);
  }, [])

  const handleClose = () => {
    /** default close logic **/
    setState({}) // setting empty state on close
  }
  
  return (
    <Popup>
      <CloseButton onClickClose={() => handleClose()}>
    </Popup>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yep, that would be EASY! we use class component, no hooksa at all. I tried with no success const handleOnClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            clientCards: {},
            clientInfos: {},
            clientSubscriptions: {},
        })
        this.props.show = !this.props.show
    }

Comment: use the set state functions that are in the react class. the concept remains the same. make sure your data is in the state and then clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the `InfoCustomer` component always rendered and shown/hidden from a prop, you could have the parent component conditionally render it.

Something like so:

```
class parentComp extends React.Component {
   *component logic*

   return (
      <div>
         {this.state.show && <InfoCustomer/>} 
      </div>
   )
}
```

This way, when you close the modal, the component will be unmounted and the state will be cleared. You'll have to rework the `InfoCustomer` component to no longer use `componentDidUpdate` and instead use `componentDidMount` to perform your fetch.

Comment: Yep I gonna try to create a "normal" component w/ didmount & unmount. I  will report when finished